# How to correctly handle dakuten and handakuten Japanese characters in mysql?

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, nscharacterset

Disclaimer:

1. Database is `ut8mb4_unicode_520_ci`
2. Table field is `ut8mb4_unicode_520_ci`

How do you correctly query a table field that contains dakuten or handakuten Japanese characters? [Dakuten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakuten).

Currently, it seems that the base character is returned, even when the query is ran for the tenten version.

**Example Data**

Given `へ` and `ぺ`. 
And a row with `ID: 199, post_title: 'へ';`

**Scenario 1**

Run:

```
SELECT 'へ' = 'ぺ'; 

-- Returns 0. Correct
```

**Scenario 2**

Run:

```
SELECT ID, post_title 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_title = 'へ';

-- Returns row 199. Correct
```

**Scenario 3**

But, for some reason, when I run this query, it still returns record 199, noting the different title value.

Run:

```
SELECT ID, post_title 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_title = 'ぺ';

-- Returns row 199. Incorrect
```

**Example Image**

An image would explain better (I'm just using union to better diplay everything in one screenshot):

[image]

Is there a solid approach to working with these characters? All other Japanese characters seem to work fine, its just the dakuten versions are treated like their bases in queries only.

Comment: are you using proper collation?

Comment: I'm reading in to it now. It seems utf general is case sensitive, and utf unicode is case insensitive for Japanese characters. Running tests now to see if swapping works

Comment: There is something funky with certain unicode collations I think: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79977

Comment: `HEX('へぺ')` is `E381B8 E381BA`; is that what you have?

Comment: I can confirm swapping it from `520` to `utf8_general_ci` restores the expected behaviour. But I don't feel like that is a great solution..

Comment: general_ci is much older; even 520 is not the latest Unicode standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the collation you used (utf8mb4_unicode_ci, utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci and utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci) only compares character's base letter. For example, 'ぺ' = 'へ' + U+309A ◌゚, 'へ' is the base letter of 'ぺ'. So for your case, all 3 characters' base letter is same, 'へ'. So it is correct result for those collations return '1'.

MySQL team is developing a new Japanese collation for utf8mb4 character set. It will differentiate these dakuten characters from base character. It will come soon.

Comment: Thanks @Xing Zhang. Is there any documentation on that? Or reference material?

Comment: Thanks.  I assume "come soon" means 8.0.x and not 5.7.xx?

Comment: @Chris. Please refer to A.11.13 section in [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-cjk.html). It explains how these collations compare Japanese character KA and GA. I think it is same as your question.

Comment: @RickJames. I suppose it is 8.0.1+.

Comment: @XingZhang A.11.13 is exactly the answer. I wasn't aware of the termprimary weight in mysql. So it seems like I have two options - revert to _bin or _general (a non-UCA) OR wrap queries in hex - like: 
`SELECT HEX('へ') = HEX('ぺ') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;`

Comment: @XingZhang Btw - great read up. The entire doc you linked is really interesting for the CJK in general

Comment: If you are going to compare HEX to HEX, you probably do not need to specify a collation; if you do, it may as well be `ascii_ci`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'へ' = 'ぺ' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; --> 0  (ditto for general_ci)
SELECT 'へ' = 'ぺ' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci; --> 1
```

The latter is a *newer* Unicode standard, so it is, in theory, more correct.

But what are you really doing?  Probably comparing one column to another?  Are they both `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`?  (The database and the connection don't matter.)

Or is one side of `=` a column and the other is a literal?

Do you establish the collation when connecting?

**Addenda**

In version 8.0.0, all of these give `1`:

```
utf8mb4_unicode_ci  -- a change from 0 in 5.6.12, but 1 in 5.7.15?
utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: I see nothing in the changelogs about this issue.  If you want more satisfaction, go to http://bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: Yes I am seeing all 3 return `1`. Thank you for taking the time to answer. To answer some of your questions - the context is a `WHERE` clause, column against a string literal. Yes I am setting the collation on upon connecting. In terms of the 'more satisfaction' - do you mean the question isn't really appropriate for SO? And should be moved to bugs.mysql.com ? In otherwords, are you leaning towards this being a bug (I'm always hesitant to  create noise on bug trackers unless its really a bug). Thanks again

Comment: Second clarification: I'm on mysql `v.5.7.16`.

Comment: If MySQL is correctly following the Unicode specifications (which I cannot verify), then the bug might be against Unicode (which I have not studied) instead of MySQL.

Comment: Even newer:  `SELECT 'へ' = 'ぺ' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;` --> 1.

Comment: Some limited experiments show that `LIKE` matches but `REGEXP` does not.